# Unable to run hashcat: clCreateContext(): CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: ubuntu

```
 sudo hashcat -m 1700 -a 0 -o cracked.txt hash /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt --force
```

Output:

```
hashcat (v5.1.0) starting...

OpenCL Platform #1: Intel(R) Corporation
========================================
* Device #1: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz, 1921/7686 MB allocatable, 8MCU

Hashes: 1 digests; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 16 bits, 65536 entries, 0x0000ffff mask, 262144 bytes, 5/13 rotates
Rules: 1

Applicable optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Early-Skip
* Not-Salted
* Not-Iterated
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Raw-Hash
* Uses-64-Bit

Minimum password length supported by kernel: 0
Maximum password length supported by kernel: 256

ATTENTION! Pure (unoptimized) OpenCL kernels selected.
This enables cracking passwords and salts > length 32 but for the price of drastically reduced performance.
If you want to switch to optimized OpenCL kernels, append -O to your commandline.

Watchdog: Hardware monitoring interface not found on your system.
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger disabled.

clCreateContext(): CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Started: XX
Stopped: XX
```

OS

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have OpenCL set up for your system. This is covered in the troubleshooting docs for Hashcat.

Comment: Did you google this error? There are tons of hits for it and what to do about it. This is ultimately not a security issue (or even a hashcat issue)